# SQL Server Sum rows with string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a dynamic SQL query which returns rows like below with string values & numeric values.

```
EMP col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
----------------------------
A1   4     4    3   3   3
A2   4     2    5   3   3
A3  sd     3    3   1   sd
A4   3     4    3   3   3
```

Now I need a new column which sums col1 to col5 and creates a total sum column where it should ignore the string values as in row 3. There are no NULL values

How could I achieve this? Using `ISNUMERIC` might be the solution, but I'm not sure how to use it in such a scenario.

Comment: you could do a CASE WHERE col1 IN (1,2,3,etc...) then sum.  (that's the basic idea anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx) Expression to determine whether the value is a number. If it is a number then either cast the value to an INT or DECIMAL data type, otherwise use 0 so it doesn't effect the sum.

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1 THEN CAST(col1 as INT) ELSE 0 END
   + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col2) = 1 THEN CAST(col2 as INT) ELSE 0 END
   + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col3) = 1 THEN CAST(col3 as INT) ELSE 0 END
   + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col4) = 1 THEN CAST(col4 as INT) ELSE 0 END
   + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col5) = 1 THEN CAST(col5 as INT) ELSE 0 END as SumValue
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: OP does mention that they want to ignore the values in `col3`

Comment: @paqogomez No you miss read. The OP wrote "I need a new column which sums col1 to col5" and "it should ignore the string values as in row 3".  It didn't ask for ignoring a column. Even so, this is just an example and the OP can modify to include or omit columns as needed.

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood.  In any respect, I had already upvoted you. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQL Server 2012, [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) avoids [pitfalls commonly encountered with ISNUMERIC](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
       ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int, col1), 0) +
       ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int, col2), 0) +
       ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int, col3), 0) +
       ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int, col4), 0) +
       ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int, col5), 0) AS total
FROM Employee
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91fbf/6)

Comment: yeah i am using SQL SERVER 2012.. never used TRY_CONVERT before.. looks interesting.. I know about the pitfalls of ISNUMERIC coz I have faced them before myself.. but in this particular case for me it wont be a problem coz the numbers come from count function

Comment: but it deserves an upvote too.. for introducing to a new SQL function

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a big case statement:

```
select q.*,
       ((case when isnumeric(col1) = 1 then cast(col1 as int) else 0 end) +
        (case when isnumeric(col2) = 1 then cast(col2 as int) else 0 end) +
        (case when isnumeric(col3) = 1 then cast(col3 as int) else 0 end) +
        (case when isnumeric(col4) = 1 then cast(col4 as int) else 0 end) +
        (case when isnumeric(col5) = 1 then cast(col5 as int) else 0 end)
       ) as newcol  
from q;
```

`isnumeric()` should be sufficient for your purposes.  You might need fancier logic if you only want positive integers or want to exclude exponential notations or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with isnumeric:

```
select
emp,
(case when isnumeric(col1) = 1 then cast(col1 as int) else 0 end) +
col2...
from table1
```